# My PHP Code is Not Updating Values In Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache, sql-update

I have tried to write a code that update category in the database using admin panel but whenever i try to do that it won't work and i don't get any errors to look into it, please help guys; thanks a lot

PHP Code:

```
<?php

               if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
                   $edit_id = $_GET['edit'];
                $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category_id = $edit_id ";
                $edit_get_result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
                if (!$edit_get_result) {
                    die("Edit Get Result Query FAILED");
                }
                while ($category_name_row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($edit_get_result)) {
                    $category_name = $category_name_row['category_name'];
                }
                ?>
                <center>
                 <form action="category.php" method="POST">

                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="update_category">Update Category</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="update_category" value="<?php if(isset($category_name)){echo $category_name; } ?>" name="update_category" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Category Name">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" name="update_category_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>

                </form>
            </center>

                <?php

                if (isset($_POST['update_category_submit'])) {
                    $category_name = $_POST['update_category'];
                    $query = "UPDATE categories SET category_name = '$category_name' WHERE category_id = $edit_id ";
                    $final_update_query_result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
                    if (!$final_update_query_result) {
                        die("Final Update Query Result FAILED");
                    }
                }
            }


                ?>
```

Comment: P.S: $connection is fine and it's on the top of the original code, my delete and add function works, it's just not updating

Comment: All your code, including the section to update the row, is within the outer if statement. So it won't run unless `$_GET['edit']` is set, which it won't be after you submit the form.

Comment: You want to read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), your code is vulnerable.

Comment: **NEVER** use raw user input in your SQL queries. this is not safe. have a look at the link provided by stickybit

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code. You need to pass edit_id in your form POST. I have put it in a hidden input and set it's value according to the GET parameter from top of your php part.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
    $edit_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_GET['edit']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category_id = '$edit_id' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if(!$result) {
    die("Edit Get Result Query FAILED");
    }

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $category_name = $row['category_name'];
    }
?>
<center>
<form action="category.php" method="POST">

<div class="form-group">
<label for="update_category">Update Category</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="update_category" value="<?php if(isset($category_name)){echo $category_name; } ?>" name="update_category" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Category Name">
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="edit_id" value="<?php if(isset($edit_id)) echo $edit_id;?>">
<button type="submit" name="update_category_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>

</form>
</center>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['update_category_submit']) && isset($_POST['edit_id'])) {
    $category_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['update_category']);
    $edit_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['edit_id']);

    $query = "UPDATE categories SET category_name = '$category_name' WHERE category_id = $edit_id ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if (!$result) {
    die("Final Update Query Result FAILED");
    }
    else echo "Final Update Query Result Success";
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi have noticed that you have used raw inputs. try avoiding it. Also noticed your code had extra curly braces at the end.

Please try using the following code after replacing your end page section php script.

```
if (isset($_POST['update_category_submit'])) {
    $category_name = $_POST['update_category'];
    $query = "UPDATE categories SET category_name = '$category_name' WHERE category_id = $edit_id ";
    $final_update_query_result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if (!$final_update_query_result) {
        die("Final Update Query Result FAILED");
    }
}
```

And Change your query variable to the following:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category_id = ".$edit_id;
```